# Resize output of map function output with css class

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to resize the images in the map function even more to make them smaller. I try to put classes on divs as well as the images but it just doesn't take. I manage to push the images up and down but I don't manage to resize them. I want to shorten the height and possibly width to keep the ratios. I have tried changing size in .container, .display-show and .display-show-img in the css.

I feel like I am misunderstanding something about the map function?

Thankful for any pointers! :)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

const DisplayShows = () => {
  const [series, setSeries] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let response = await axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://content.viaplay.se/pc-se/serier/samtliga')
      setSeries(response.data._embedded['viaplay:blocks'][0]._embedded['viaplay:products'])
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="container">{series.map((serie) => {
      return (
        <div className="display-show" data-cy="display-show">
          <img
            className="display-show-img"
            src={serie.content.images.landscape.url}
            alt={serie.id}
            key={serie.id}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}</div>
  )
}
```

Here is my css:

```css
.display-show {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13%;
  width: calc(25% - ((20px) * 0.75));
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 10%;
}

.display-show:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.display-show img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  size: 10%;
}

.header {
  background-color: black;
  height: 9%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding: -5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header img {
  height: 60%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  position: absolute;
}

.footer {
  background-color: black;
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```